# Deploying to Glassfish classpath not set for com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource

Tags: eclipse, deployment, glassfish, ear

Glassfish is not loading the `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` package.

The following error is thrown

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: 
Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set    
for:com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
Error Code: 0 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy
(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:517)...
```

I have copied the mysql-connector jar file to the `lib` directory of Glassfish but I still get the above error.

How do I ensure that Glassfish can find my JDBC driver for my deployed application?

Comment: Sara, I have posted an answer that will likely point you in the right direction. However, it would great if you edited your question so that it contained the error you see in the Glassfish log files.

Comment: @Rob, done! I still have the issue.

Comment: Ok Sara, thanks for that. Edit to answer on its way with more specific info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to make the MySQL JDBC jar file available to Glassfish.

http://ushainformatique.com/blog/2010/03/19/jdbcwithglassfish/

EDIT:

### How do I use different JDBC drivers? Where should I copy the jar(s)?

> It is recommended to place JDBC drivers, that are used by all the
>   applications in the domain, in domain-dir/lib or
>   domain-dir/lib/classes. A restart of the application server instance
>   is required today so that the JDBC drivers are visible to applications
>   deployed in the domain.

From https://blogs.oracle.com/sivakumart/entry/classloaders_in_glassfish_an_attempt

So move the jar file into the lib dir below the domain into which you are deploying your app. The default Glassfish domain is domain1.

Restart Glassfish and this should work.

There is a Maven Glassfish plugin which may be worth evaluating http://maven-glassfish-plugin.java.net/ Using Maven and this plugin would help automate the deployment step. This would be more robust than doing manual deployments. Your call though of course.

Comment: Rob thanks. My manager is using Netbeans and he told me from the beginning to add the jar file there. So I have already added it there. But it seems that with eclipse I should add it somewhere else also. Still the issue exists.

Comment: Thanks Rob it is now working. Besides that I faced another issue which kept throwing me same error afterwards. It was with the connection pool properties. I forgot  to set the properties for username and password there. Now it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Besides adding the driver to your classpath, you should try adding the appserv-rt.jar file to your project's build path (the jar is located in Glassfish's lib directory). If you don't want to include all the other jars you should first create a library containing the appserv-rt jar and then add it to your project's build path.

Comment: I found the appserv-rt.jar, but where is the build path. I use Netbeans and Payara.

Answer (score -3):

We could fix using
./asadmin start-database
This starts Derby (don't know why this is required, may be a bug, and I dont use this DB in my app)
:)

Comment: This is reguarding a MySQL connection.