# Deploying java project to remote glassfish server

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish

We have a project made in netbeans 7.3 and are about to deploying this to a remote glassfish server, everything is configured and set up properly and the connection pools for our project are also generated in glassfish.

Currently we are getting this error when deploying to the remote server:

> deploy?DEFAULT=D:\SVN\PTS62\Applicaties\Rekeningrijderwebsite\RekeningRijder\dist\RekeningRijder.war&name=RekeningRijder&contextroot=/RekeningRijder&force=true
>   failed on GlassFish Server 3+
>
> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app :
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a
>   connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for :
>   com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
>
> Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.

And the message the server generates:

> Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Class name is wrong or
>   classpath is not set for :
>   com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
>
> ```
>             at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:292)
>
>             at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:114)
>
>             at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1307)
>
>             at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:163)
>
>             at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:102)
>
>             at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:87)
>
>             ... 62 more
> ```

Google wasn't very helpfull before, so hopefully you guys/girls can help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need a mysql / java connector.

You can find it [there](http://www.mysql.fr/downloads/connector/j/). Extract the mysql-connector-java .jar from the archive. Then place it into the glassfish external lib directory {INSTALL DIR}/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext.

Restart your glassfish server.

There are more details [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966024/2015707). If that's not what you are looking for, or if it doesn't work, tell us. @+

Comment: Alright :D that is one fix for the problem, now i'm getting "Can't find bundle for base name lang.trans" this is my resource bundle for languages, do i have to edit something to bring this to glassfish remotly?

Comment: @BartPasmans Maybe you should ask another question about this issue with more details (structure of the project, type of ressource bundle, etc).

Comment: @BartPasmans i add mysql-connector to glassfish in ext folder and this problem solved. but how can i solve this problem using another solution. i add connector to jpa module build path but it not works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Right, you just lack mysql lib, just find and download `mysql-connector-java-5.x.x-bin.jar` copy to `E:\Projects\glassfish3.1.1\glassfish\lib` then restart server and enjoy !!!